# Python locally suppress warnings in thread-safe way

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multithreaded program with a line that causes a warning I want to silence. I don't want to silence warnings anywhere else in the code.

I could do this, as suggested [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings):

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    line_that_causes_warning()
```

But the docs also say that [it's not thread-safe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings), because it sets the module-level warning filter.

I realize I could probably solve that with something crazy like protecting this section with a lock, but is there a nice way to make this thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with threading interface. Lock `acquire()` method will be called when the with block is started to execution, after the exit of the block `release()` method will be called.

```
import warnings
import threading

lock_for_purpose = threading.RLock()
print(lock_for_purpose)
def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with lock_for_purpose:
    print("lock is done")
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        fxn()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said, I realize locking is possible, but I don't want to protect the function with a lock—I'd want something like `contextlib.suppress` that doesn't impede multithreading, but for warnings. (I realize that this may not be possible but I could find nothing to confirm it isn't).